# Chrome flickers when scrolling with mouse wheel, relocating div to $(document).scrollTop()

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

what I am trying to achieve is a div on top of my page, which resides there even when the user scrolls the page. Seems like a common task and I found plenty of solutions on the web.

The easiest way seems to be with jQuery: ("header" being the id of my div)

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   $("#header").css({
    "top": $(document).scrollTop() + "px"
   });
});
```

It works fine in Firefox! In Chrome (37.0.2062.103 m), however, I get some very weird flickering of the header div, when I scroll the page up or down **with the mouse wheel**. (Scrolling via keyboard, scroll bar or keeping the middle mouse button pressed works seamlessly). It seems like the repositioning of the div happens somewhat delayed, as if the page is scrolled first and then the div is moved to the new position.

I would have liked to demonstrate this to you guys in JSFiddle, but when I execute it there, it works fine even in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/2tLgtn6c/3/embedded/result/

You can see the odd behaviour here: -- site no longer exists --

It's the exact same code as in the JSFiddle example. I am also posting it below.

Any ideas, what I could try? Apparently, Chrome is indeed capable of showing it correctly, as it works within JSFiddle... Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Linus

index.htm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html lang="en">
<body>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
function drawHorizontalHeader(width, height) {

  var headerDiv = document.createElement("div");
  $("body").append(headerDiv);

  headerDiv.id = "header";
  headerDiv.innerHTML = "Horizontal header.";
  headerDiv.style.border = "1px solid blue";
  headerDiv.style.position = "absolute";

  $(headerDiv).width(width);
  $(headerDiv).height(height);

}


function drawMain(width, height) {

  var mainDiv = document.createElement("div");
  $("body").append(mainDiv);

  mainDiv.innerHTML = "Main.";
  mainDiv.style.border = "1px solid red";

  $(mainDiv).width(width);
  $(mainDiv).height(height);
}


function drawPage() {

  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();

  $("body").css("margin", "0px");

  drawHorizontalHeader(windowWidth, windowHeight / 5);
  drawMain(windowWidth, windowHeight * 2);
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
  $("#header").css({
    "top": $(document).scrollTop() + "px"
  });
});


// Draw the page initially.
drawPage();
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using `position: fixed`?

Comment: What do you mean? If I use "position: fixed", the div will not even stay at the top of the page: http://jsfiddle.net/2LzmcduL/1/embedded/result/

Comment: It's interesting that it doesn't flicker in Firefox.  It flickers in Chrome, IE, and Opera (but not Safari).  It's a function of the css being applied after the window has been scrolled.  Using `position:fixed` should fix it, as long as you remove the window scroll event.

Comment: Your right! This works. Strange that I found this scroll-repositioning solution instead of this much easier solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scroll` event will be firing a lot of times, which will cause your browser to redraw the page. This can cause flicker.

Rather than recalculating the absolute position of your element every time the scroll position of the window changes, you can use the CSS property `position: fixed`:

HTML:

```
<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="main">main</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
    position: fixed;
    height: 2em;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#main {
    margin-top: 2em;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bgb8oa1c/) showing what I mean. Hopefully you can adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Yes, thank you. This does exactly what I need for now!